# Force figure placement in text with lstinputlisting

Tags: floats, listings, positioning

I have been looking everywhere and I found the ways of doing this with images with `\usepackage{float}` for `\includegraphics`. But I also have texts from `.txt` files that I have as in `\lstinputlisting` that I would also like to force.

I don't really understand the documentation of how placement works.

> 5.1 Space and placement
>
> float=[*] *<subset of tbphi>* or `float`     **floatplacement**
>   
> makes sense on individual displayed listings only and
>   lets them float. The argument controls where LATEX is allowed to put
>   the float: at the top or bottom of the current/next page, on a
>   separate page, or here where the listing is. The optional star can be
>   used to get a double-column float in a two-column document
>
> floatplacement=*<place specifiers>*   **tbp**
>   
> is used as place specifier if
>   float is used without value.

Any ideas how I force the code below with `\lstinputlisting`?

```
\lstinputlisting[float=h,frame=tb,
    caption=Iteration: 2. Variable importance for unpruned decision tree ,captionpos=b, belowcaptionskip=2cm ,label=zebra]{results/maybe_80_20.txt}
```

Comment: Probably you are using the `H` specifier for figures. Why don't you use it for listings? But please consider that you really disable all of the advantages and the concept of floats.

Comment: @TeXnician: This is not a duplicate. E.g. `\lstinputlisting[float=H,…` will not work. See my note about this in my answer below.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks for the information. Voted for reopening too.

Answer (score 10):

Package `listings` supports captions for not floating listings. See the initial paragraph in section 5.7, "Captions" in the `listings` manual:

> In despite of LaTeX standard behaviour, captions and floats are independent from each other here; you can use captions with non-floating listings.

So you can simple remove the `float` option from your example and use, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\lstinputlisting[frame=tb,caption=Source of this file,
  captionpos=b,belowcaptionskip=2cm,
  label=zebra]{\jobname.tex}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

You have to use option `float` only for those listings, that should float.

Note: `listings` also allows page breaks inside non-floating listings with captions! So you have to use either a `\parbox` or `minipage` around them, if page breaks should not be allowed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[frame=tb,caption=Source of this file,
  captionpos=b,belowcaptionskip=2cm,
  label=zebra]{\jobname.tex}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: good result]

while

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]

%\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[frame=tb,caption=Source of this file,
  captionpos=b,belowcaptionskip=2cm,
  label=zebra]{\jobname.tex}
%\end{minipage}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: not so good restult]

BTW: Option `H` of package `float` cannot be used with `\lstinputlisting`:

```
% CAVEAT: THIS WILL NOT WORK! DON'T DO IT!!!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\lstinputlisting[float=H,frame=tb,
  caption=Source of this file,
  captionpos=b,belowcaptionskip=2cm,
  label=zebra]{\jobname.tex}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

would result

[image: the listing is missing]

As you can see, the listing is missing (without any error message). So: Don't do this!